# current_timestamp default column value working in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, datetime, timestamp

This MySql query runs fine in Windows:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts`.`table` (
  `idTable` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Column1` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idTable`));
```

In [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), it is giving the following error:

> ERROR 1067: Invalid default value for `'Column1'`

How do I give `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default value for `'Column1'` in Ubuntu?

The version of MySql is this:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Comment: Different versions installed. What does `select @@version;` show in both (Windows and Linux)? I think the option for `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `datetime` columns was added in 5.6 version. Your Linux installation has probably an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the different versions installed in the two environments.

The option for `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `datetime` columns was added in 5.6 version (specifically in 5.6.5). See the doumentation about [the `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html):

> The `TIMESTAMP` and **(as of MySQL 5.6.5) `DATETIME` data types offer automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time**. For more information, see Section 11.3.5, [“Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME`”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Most probably your Linux installation has an older version while the Windows has a newer. The solution would be to upgrade to the newer version (or have it installed besides the old).

General info about upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6 here: [Upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) and specific about [upgrading in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614886/upgrading-mysql-5-5-to-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

Don't forget to backup your data before you upgrade and run `mysql_upgrade` immediately after.